# "be" as the main verb of clause

Tags: subjunctives, mandative

> 1. Stackoverflow requires all users **be** polite and helpful when answering a question.
> 2. Stackoverflow requires that all users act polite and helpful when answering a question.

Is the first sentence correct?

If so, what is the name of this clause?
How natural and formal is it, especially compared to the second sentence?

Which one is more preferred in speaking, and which one in writing?

Comment: The second sentence is wrong. SO can not require that users **are** polite. Only that they **act** politely... so "be" is preferred... though I'd put the "that" in... "SO requires **that** all users be polite and helpful when answering a question."

Comment: Consider: *"Stackoverflow requires that all users [be/are/should be] polite and helpful when answering a question."* This is a mandative construction, and all three versions have the same meaning: the same mandative interpretation. Your 1st example is a subjunctive mandative and uses a subjunctive clause. Your 2nd example is a covert mandative (which tends to be fairly rare, especially in AmE). You can probably get more info on this topic via the mandative and subjunctive tags. For vetted info, there's H&P's *CGEL*, pages 993-1002, which cover the mandative and subjunctive.

Comment: There are several questions here, it'd be better to only have one. If there's a commonality between these questions, ask about that. One of those examples says 'be', the other inserts a 'that' and changes to 'are'. Which are you asking about? I think this is going to get opinions as answers, and it will be hard for the answers to answer the whole question, whatever it is.

Comment: @F.E. is the second sentence correct but rare in your opinion?

Comment: @DCShannon The flow of the questions,imo, is very clear. All the questions are tightly related, and answering either one without having answered to the previous ones does not make much sense.

Comment: But now it's a completely different question. :(

Comment: Did you **intentionally** add "that" to the second question or was it an accident, or was it accidentally omitted from the first question?

Comment: @Catija If you think it's a different question now, then I think my point has been demonstrated.

Comment: @Catija Why do you think that? The focus of the question was on the use of **be** as the main verb of the clause, and not on the second sentence. What you suggested before ("SO requires that all users be ....") is basically the same as the first sentence.

Comment: @AmD In the 3 versions in my previous comment, I'd consider all of them to be grammatical--though the covert mandative tends to be rarely seen in edited prose in the more formal registers, imo. Here's what H&P *CGEL* says, on page 995: *"Clear cases of the covert construction are fairly rare, and indeed in AmE are of somewhat marginal acceptability. In AmE the subjunctive is strongly favored over the* should *construction, while BrE shows the opposite preference."* -- Though, research seems to indicate that the subjunctive mandative usage has significantly increased in BrE in recent times.

Comment: @ F.E. thank you. Therefore the subjunctive appears to be popular among BrE speakers as well! I didn't know that the subjunctive was strongly recommended in that type of context.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct, but the wording isn't as clear as it can be. It would be better written as:

> StackOverflow requires all users **to** be polite and helpful when answering a question.

or even:

> StackOverflow requires **that** all users be polite and helpful when answering a question.

The second sentence makes sense, but it is ungrammatical. There should be adverbs within it:

> StackOverflow requires that all users act **politely** and **helpfully** when answering a question.

Or, alternatively:

> StackOverflow requires that all users act **politely** and **(that they) are helpful** when answering a question.

(The "that they" here is optional, but it helps to clarify the sentence.)